# Function returning 4 as a Prime number

Tags: c, algorithm

I wrote a function to check if a number is prime or composite. Something is wrong with it. It returns 4 as prime.

Needed help in fixing it

```c
int c_sqrt(int nb)
{
    int i;

    i = 1;
    if (nb == 0)
        return (0);
    while (i * i < nb)
        i++;
    if ((nb % i) == 0)
        return (i);
    return (0);
}

int isPrime(int x)
{
    int i;
    int root;

    i = 2;
    root = c_sqrt(x);
    while (i++ <= root)
    {
        if (x % i == 0)
            return (0);
    }
    return (1);
}
```

Comment: How do you know if any of these work correctly? The best thing to do when stuck is write unit tests to verify.

Comment: `c_sqrt()` is not needed.  Instead `while (i <= root/i) { ...  i+;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working because, after below lines, `i` become 3 instead of 2.

```
i = 2;
root = c_sqrt(x);
while (i++ <= root)
```

If you change location of increasing `i` like below, `isPrime(4)` will be O.K.

```
i = 2;
root = c_sqrt(x);
while (i <= root)
{
    if (x % i++ == 0)
        return (0);
}
```

But `c_sqrt(int nb)` function also has some problem with an input like `8`, so you need to fix that too.

```
/*
if ((nb % i) == 0)
    return (i);
return (0);
*/
return i;
```

Like above, bottom part of your code is actually not necessary, just returning `i` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `while (i++ <= root)`. `i` starts as 2, and the `++` increments it, so you end up jumping straight to `x % 3` and skipping `x % 2` entirely. You can fix it by doing `while (i <= root)` instead and adding `++i;` to the end of the loop body. Alternatively, you can use a `for` loop instead to be a bit cleaner.